# JavaScript Character Counter Resets to 0 after PostBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this JavaScript that counts character from a textarea which is the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#count').click(counter);
        $('#txtComment').change(counter);
        $('#txtComment').keydown(counter);
        $('#txtComment').keypress(counter);
        $('#txtComment').keyup(counter);
        $('#txtComment').blur(counter);
        $('#txtComment').focus(counter);
        $('#txtComment').focusin(counter);
        $('#txtComment').focusout(counter);
        $('#txtComment').mousedown(counter);
        $('#txtComment').mouseenter(counter);
        $('#txtComment').show(counter);
        $('#txtComment').load(counter);
        $('#txtComment').submit(counter);
        $('#btnSubmit').click(counter);
    });

    counter = function () {
        var value = $('#txtComment').val();

        if (value.length == 0) {
            $('#wordCount').html(0);
            $('#totalChars').html(0);
            $('#charCount').html(0); // I only use this one.
            $('#charCountNoSpace').html(0);
            return;
        }

        var regex = /\s+/gi;
        var wordCount = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
        var totalChars = value.length;
        var charCount = value.trim().length; // I only use this one.
        var charCountNoSpace = value.replace(regex, '').length;

        $('#wordCount').html(wordCount);
        $('#totalChars').html(totalChars);
        $('#charCount').html(charCount); // I only use this one.
        $('#charCountNoSpace').html(charCountNoSpace);
    };
```

And I am displaying the counter in a span:

```
<span id="totalChars">0</span> characters
```

When the Page is not PostBack, the count seems to be working fine. On the page, I have a submit button which is an ASP.NET control that runs at server. When it comes to the scenario where the button is clicked, the page is doing a PostBack, after submitting the data, It will display the same page, retains the content of the textarea, but, the count sets back to zero even when there are value/s on the textarea. As you can see, I have already put almost all of possible events the form should do.

I need to count the characters and display it after PostBack.

Comment: you need to call the counter function on $(document).ready

Comment: beat me to it @AbrahamUribe

Answer (score 0):

You can change the span tag to run at the server, so the ViewState will persiste the value after the postback.

```
<span id="totalChars" runat="server">0</span> characters
```

Answer (score 0):

The `counter` function is not firing until the `textarea` is interacted with.  After binding all your events, call the `counter` function manually (IE `counter();`) in your `$(document).ready` function and the code will be run at page load.

You might think the `load` event would do this for you, but `load` only works with elements that have a URL associated with them (like images and scripts, [see the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) for more information).

Comment: If it is a traditional postback yes, as a PostBack is just an HTTP `POST` with the WebForms framework doing extra magic for you.  However, a partial PostBack (using the `UpdatePanel` control) uses AJAX to update the page.  In this instance the `ready` function would only fire once.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I tought it was in AsyncPostBack from ScriptManager because I just answer this in another question.

Comment: Hi Nathan, can you show me how to call it manually? I'm a noob with jQuery.

Comment: Just write `counter();` after all your event binding in the ready function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery Cookies Plug-in](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to persist, like:

to save: `jQuery.cookie("cookie_counter", totalChars);`

to get: `var totalChars = jQuery.cookie("cookie_counter");`

Answer (score 0):

1. on the submit button "**OnClientClick**" event you can call a **javascript function.**
2. save the character count in the **session**.
3. after page loads completely assign the value stored in **session** to the **span**.
4. you should create a **session variable before** only to make use of it.

eg. function setVar(){ alert("Testing"); <% Session("TempVar") = "setVar Test" %> }